# How to report import module error in console for Angular dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, dependencies

I'm writing a set of Angular directives. Some of them will use other 3rd Angular dependencies (e.g. `ngFileUpload`, `ui-select`). Currently I declare all of them like this:

```
angular.module('module1', ['ngFileUpload']) 
  .directive('MyDirective1NeedNgFileUpload', function() {
     // ...
  });

angular.module('module2', ['ui-select']) 
  .directive('MyDirective1NeedUiSelect', function() {
     // ...
  });

angular.module('myLibrary', ['module1', 'module2']);
```

Normally, user will have to include three js files in a real application like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="/path/to/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/ui-select.js"></script>
  <script src="/path/to/myLibrary.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

// in app.js
angular.module('myapp', [
  'myLibrary', 
  'ngFileUpload',
  'ui-select'
]);
```

If I only use `module1` in application 1, I don't need `ui-select` at all. But I still need to include `ui-select`, otherwise browser will report an error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/...`.

What I want to ask/do, is that, I want to lazy load 3rd dependencies, only when they are really needed, or simply throw a more concrete error message about what is missing.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

So as you said some users may need just `module1` features, some `module2` some both.

you publish your library as a combined module as well `angular.module('myLibrary', ['module1', 'module2']);`

As `module1` and `module2` goes by itself, tell in your docs that user can use that module alone or `myLibrary` for combined features.

```
angular.module('userApp', ['module1']);// in case single module is enough for user
angular.module('userApp', ['myLibrary']); // incase both module features will be used
```

Comment: In my real case, I have a directive `<form-control>`, it can be an input, or a dropdown list, or a datetime picker, or a file upload. If user never use file upload, they don't have to include `ng-file-upload.js`. If user never use dropdown list, they don't have to include `ui-select.js`. Imagine some libraries are quite large, I'd find a way to load libraries on demand.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My original description could be mis-leading. I have put more details into original question.